# Numerical optimisation for multivariate Gaussians

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, probability-distributions, convex-optimization, linear-algebra

Hi,

I want to calculate

$
f_{\mathbf x}(x_1,\ldots,x_k)\, =
\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{k/2}|\boldsymbol\Sigma|^{1/2}}
\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}({\mathbf x}-{\boldsymbol\mu})^T{\boldsymbol\Sigma}^{-1}({\mathbf x}-{\boldsymbol\mu})
\right),
$

for a huge ($k$ up 100.000) multivariate Gaussian distribution where $\boldsymbol\Sigma$ is sparse. Cholesky decomposition works fine if the $k$ is smallish and has the advantage that the determinant can be calculated easily from the factors. For larger $k$ I would like to use CG (conjugate gradient optimization), which is really fast to compute $({\mathbf x}-{\boldsymbol\mu})^T{\boldsymbol\Sigma}^{-1}({\mathbf x}-{\boldsymbol\mu})$, however I still need the determinant and have no idea how to (efficiently) compute or approximate it.

Are there any algorithms designed for this problem?

Thank you!

Manuel

Comment: since the determinant is just for normalization, you should not need it if you use this distrubution to compute expectation values; and by the way, what is CG?

Comment: @Carlos CG: Conjugate gradient optimization (I modified my question accordingly). You are right, the mean, median, variance, covariance are trivial to "compute". Unfortunately I need the density.

Comment: For what do you need the density? If this is for maximum likelihood estimation, did you consider to use composite likelihood instead?



Answer (score 1):

Here are a few references that should help you get started in the area of approximating determinants:

[Approximation of the determinant of large sparse symmetric positive definite matrices](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-lat/0008007)

[Determinant Approximations](http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.0437)

[Matrices, Moments and Quadrature](http://books.google.fr/books?id=IZvkFET3LlwC&dq=matrices+moments+quadrature&lr=&source=gbs_navlinks_s)